# JavaScript not working / firing on IE11 - I'm using onclick=function() in my script - SCRIPT5 console error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, internet-explorer-11

I have created an embed for my organisation's website. It works on all browsers (including Edge) but not on IE 11. I have read lots about onclick not working properly in IE but nothing about using onclick in the script itself. I'm getting a SCTIPT5: Access is denied....

Below is a snip[pet of my script. It fires on all browsers except IE 11. Anyone got any insight?

```
//Variables
var count = 0 //Yes button click count
var q1 = document.getElementById('q1');
var q2 = document.getElementById('q2');
var q3 = document.getElementById('q3');
var q4 = document.getElementById('q4');
var q5 = document.getElementById('q5');
var cloud0 = document.getElementById('cloud0');
var cloud1 = document.getElementById('cloud1');
var cloud2 = document.getElementById('cloud2');
var cloud3 = document.getElementById('cloud3');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
var result0 = document.getElementById('result0');

//Tracking
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
var qNum = 1;

//Question 1 Yes and No button. Actions when they are clicked.
yes1.onclick = function() {
  count ++ ;
    q1.style.display = "none";
    q2.style.display = "inline";
        if (count === 1) {
        cloud0.style.display = "none";
        cloud1.style.display = "block";
    }
    sendEvent(qNum,'yes');
    qNum++;
}

no1.onclick = function() {
    q1.style.display = "none";
    q2.style.display = "inline";
    sendEvent(qNum,'no');
    qNum++;
}


//Question 2 Yes and No button. Actions when they are clicked.
yes2.onclick = function() {
  count ++ ;
    q2.style.display = "none";
    q3.style.display = "inline";
        if (count === 1) {
        cloud0.style.display = "none";
        cloud1.style.display = "block";
    } else if (count === 2) {
        cloud1.style.display = "none";
        cloud2.style.display = "block";
    }
    sendEvent(qNum,'yes');
    qNum++;
}

no2.onclick = function() {
    q2.style.display = "none";
    q3.style.display = "inline";
    sendEvent(qNum,'no');
    qNum++;
}
```

On each click of a button in the HTML file the next question and new buttons are displayed and the previous ones hidden.

Here is a snippet of my HTML to help:

```
<div class="quiz" id="quiz">

  <div role="question" class="q" id="q1">
    <div class="layoutq">
      <p class="qnumber" id="qnumber1">1</p>
      <P class="qtext" id="qtext1">Do you usually go up to or over the limit on your cards or overdraft?</P>
    </div>
    <div class="layoutbutton">
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="yes1">Yes</button>
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="no1">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="question" class="q" id="q2">
    <div class="layoutq">
      <P class="qnumber" id="qnumber2">2</P>
      <P class="qtext" id="qtext2">Have you borrowed more money to cover your debt payments?</P>
    </div>
    <div class="layoutbutton">
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="yes2" class="yesbutton">Yes</button>
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="no2">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="question" class="q" id="q3">
    <div class="layoutq">
      <P class="qnumber" id="qnumber3">3</P>
      <P class="qtext" id="qtext3">Have you considered or applied for a debt consolidation loan recently?</P>
    </div>
    <div class="layoutbutton">
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="yes3">Yes</button>
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="no3">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="question" class="q" id="q4">
    <div class="layoutq">
      <P class="qnumber" id="qnumber4">4</P>
      <P class="qtext" id="qtext4">Are you having issues paying your household bills?</P>
    </div>
    <div class="layoutbutton">
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="yes4">Yes</button>
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="no4">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div role="question" class="q" id="q5">
    <div class="layoutq">
      <P class="qnumber" id="qnumber5">5</P>
      <P class="qtext" id="qtex5">Have you borrowed following job loss, illness or an upheaval in your life?</P>
    </div>
    <div class="layoutbutton">
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="yes5">Yes</button>
      <button role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-o btn-sm" id="no5">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Many thanks folks

Mark

Comment: Any console errors? "Not working properly" is quite a vague error description

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53667376/edit) and then `[<>]` the snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Where do you define yes1, no1, yes2 and no2 ???

Comment: I'm not sure I'm a bit of novice to all this to be honest. On IE nothing happens when you click a button, it's just stationary. Cheers, Mark

Comment: Where is your `var no1 = document.getElementById.....`

Comment: They're defined in my HTML as IDs

Comment: Where is your `var  qNum=0` ?

Comment: Please press F12 and look in the console. There will be several errors

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added an HTML snippet above to see if this adds context. Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: I'm getting console errors that say: SCRIPTS: Access is denied ??

Comment: You actually have the HTML in a different document than the JS, and you're doing some changes to the HTML document using `innerHTML`?

Comment: Yep that's correct

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML`, it creates all the new elements every time you do e.g. `element.innerHTML += x`. Strings are immutable, `+=` doesn't append to a string, it's just a shortcut to the redefinition: `element.innerHTML =  element.innerHTML + x`. All the previous elements you've taken a reference are gone, and new elements are created. "Access denied" error is just a way IE handles this situation in some cases.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was because I hadn't defined the yes and no button variables. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by defining the button variables in my script. All is working now. Thanks for your suggestions. mplungjan your suggestion saved my bacon!

Cheers

Comment: From your last post I can see that you had solved the issue and posted your solution. I suggest you to mark your posted solution as an answer for this thread may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I needed to do that :)